# Calculate marginal densities

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-theory

Let $f(u,v)=\mathbb{1}_{\{0\le v \le 2u\}} \cdot \mathbb{1}_{\{0\le u \le 1\}}$

How can I calculate marginal densities? I know $f(u)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(u,v)dv$ and $f(v)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(u,v)du$ but somehow got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(u)=\int_{V}f(u,v) dv=\begin{cases}\int_{0}^{2u}\ dv, & \text{ for } 0\le u \le 1 \\ 0, & \text{ else}\end{cases}$$ and
$$f(v)=\int_{U}f(u,v) du=\begin{cases}\int_{v/2}^{1}\ du, & \text{ for } 0\le v \le 2 \\ 0, & \text{ else} \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

For instance,
$$
f(u)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathbf{1}_{0\leqslant v\leqslant 2u}\mathbf{1}_{0\leqslant u\leqslant 1}\,\mathrm dv=\mathbf{1}_{0\leqslant u\leqslant 1}\int_0^{2u}\mathrm dv.
$$
Argue similarly for $f(v)$, where it might help to note that $\mathbf{1}_{0\leqslant u\leqslant 1}\mathbf{1}_{0\leqslant v\leqslant 2u}=\mathbf{1}_{0\leqslant v\leqslant 2}\mathbf{1}_{0\leqslant u\leqslant v/2}$.